# EC2 upload failed to S3

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file from an EC2 instance to S3 bucket and get this error:

```
[ec2-user@zzzzzzz parsers]$ aws s3 cp file.txt s3://bucket/output/file.txt
```

> upload failed: ./file.txt to s3://bucket/output/file.txt A client error (InvalidAccessKeyId) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

I have already configured the aws configure file in EC2 as follows:

```
[ec2-user@zzzzz parsers]$ aws configure list
```

> ```
> Name           Value                 Type           Location
> ----           -----                 ----           --------
> profile        <not set>             None           None
> access_key     ****************NTr6  config-file     
> secret_key     ****************AFJQ  config-file     
> region         us-west-2             config-file    ~/.aws/config
> ```

What else should I do to make this work?

Comment: Check that the access and secret keys are not from ec2 instance IAM role which is usually rotated and changes quite often

Comment: This happened to me after stopping / starting the instance, then running out of disk space.  Even creating an image of my instance and launching a new instance from that didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

`InvalidAccessKeyId` indicates that the Access Key and Secret Key are not valid.

Access Keys (and their corresponding Secret Keys) can be associated to either either:

- Master (or root) credentials, or
- An Identity and Access Management (IAM) user

It is recommended that Master credentials not be used on a daily basis. (See [IAM Best Practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/IAMBestPractices.html).)

If your credentials are associated with an IAM user, you can **generate a new set of credentials**:

- Go to Identity and Access Management (IAM)
- Select the User
- Manage Access Keys
- Create Access Key

A new Access Key and Secret Key will be displayed. Try using them in CLI configuration.

Up to two sets of Access Keys can be associated with a User at any time.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use IAM roles instead of IAM access keys for EC2 instances. By simply creating a IAM role to access S3 and link it to your EC2 instance, you can list, download and upload files from and to your S3 bucket(s) based on the role's policy.

It's more secure and you don't have to configure your aws credentials.